# jQuery load does not get another jquery script after loop

Tags: jquery

I'm using something like this:

**The jquery load:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.navigation a').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#load').fadeTo(200, 0).load(link + ' #load-posts', function(){ jQuery('#load').fadeTo(200, 1); });      
        });

    });
```

**The Wordpress Loop**

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post-tip-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo substr($post->post_title,0,15); ?></a>

    <div class="post-tip-item-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="display: none;">
    post tip content
    </div><!-- /#post-tip-item-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

    <script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function() {  jQuery('a.post-tip-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>').easyTooltip({ useElement: 'post-tip-item-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>'}); });</script>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
 <div class="navigation">

    <?php posts_nav_link('','','&laquo; Previous Entries') ?>


    <?php posts_nav_link('','Next Entries &raquo;','') ?>

 </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that after for example the load changes the page and gets the next posts this is not loaded anymore:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function() {  jQuery('a.post-tip-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>').easyTooltip({ useElement: 'post-tip-item-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>'}); });</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your issue, but this line of code: `var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');` can be replaced with `var link = this.href;`.  Must faster and shorter.  jQuery should only be used when it's better than native JS.

Comment: thanks for the tip - var link = this.href;

Comment: If anyone can give me a tip, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: If you want help, I'd suggest two things:  1) Clarify your question by describing in more detail what exact sequence you follow and what happens (or doesn't happen).  2) Post actual generated HTML/Javascript (you can capture it with View/Source from a browser) without any PHP in it.  Those of us who don't know PHP can't really help the way you have it now.